# Use NeoVim in collaboration with other editors in realtime?

Tags: text-editor, collaboration, vim, atom.io

I'm a NeoVim user and would like to be able to collaborate in real time with users of other editors, ala pair programming. I am aware of [Floobits](https://floobits.com/) which is a proprietary system that includes plugins for various editors. In fact I've used it before and really liked it, but I have two use cases right now: one that requires all software stays in-house so I need a self-hosted solution and others that are FOSS projects with no budgets.

The closest Open Source alternative I've run across is the MIT licensed [Firepad](https://firepad.io/#1) which uses a Firebase backend to synchronize edits between users. There is a [plugin for Atom](https://github.com/Fankserver/atom-firepad) which seems to enable those guys to work on the same file in real time but I don't see any plugins for NeoVim users like myself to join the party.

My requirements are an open-source system that can be used independently of a third party, and there has to be plugins for (or a way to hack) at least NeoVim and Atom Editor. Bonus points for Sublime Text and browser-based editors being added to the mix.

I do not care about *how* the protocol works. I can have all the systems on the same VPN so it could presume a local network, or some internet based protocol is fine.

Comment: See also my related [question on Vi and Vim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/10427/267).